# How to get specific data from array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have data like this:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
                    [category] => yyyyyyyy
                    [id] => 12345666666
                    [data] => ABCDE
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                     [name] => ZZZZZZZZZZZ
                    [category] => JJJJJJ
                    [id] => 88888888888888
                    [data] => ABCDEHIJK
                )

        )

)
```

I need to get the data from the first array only. I don't want to use a loop. I have tried this:

```
$name = $data['data'][0]['name'];
```

but that doesn't get the name. Does anyone know how I can get the specific name only from the first array?

EDIT** my code:

```
$movie_details_tmdb = $tmdb->searchMovie($search);
$movie_details_tmdb_results = json_decode(json_encode($movie_details_tmdb), true);
$id = $movie_details_tmdb_results['results'][0]['id'];
```

it's in the same format as the code above.

Comment: That should work, can you show more of your php code?

Comment: I updated it. I'm not sure why it isn't working? :/

Comment: well.. this is embarrassing .. I figured out what was wrong.. the search wasn't returning any results. Can you put your answer as an answer at the bottom so I can mark it answered? thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm wondering why you're encoding and then right after decoding JSON o.O ?

Comment: @AndrewButler It might be better for you to add your own answer and accept that. I didn't really answer anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you have problems with json?

**(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL json >= 1.2.0)**

The better way to convert object to array:

```
$arr = (array) $obj;
```